# Open MPI in Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, openmpi

I want to run Open MPI program in Xcode. I follow http://www.macresearch.org/compiling-running-and-debugging-mpi-programs-xcode tutorial. I am getting output for MPI_test executable. but when i am running mpiexec, i  got the following error:

- Failed to find or execute the following executable:
- Cannot continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running `mpiexec` from the command line, you are probably not starting in the correct directory. Your executable's directory is in either the *Debug* or *Release* directory in your project directory depending on which configuration you select when you build. If you named your project MPI_test, go into the appropriate directory and type `./MPI_test` and make sure the program runs. If it doesn't, you're not in the correct directory. Once you've found the correct directory, you can type `mpiexec -np 4 MPI_test` and that should run as well.

If you are following the instructions to run `mpiexec` within Xcode, it wlll only work if you name your project MPI_test. Instead of setting the second argument in the custom executable to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/MPI_test`, set it to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)` and it will work no matter what you name your project as long as it's a valid command line program name (e.g. it can't have spaces).

Comment: :I am in debug folder but i am getting error**Failed to find or execute the following executable:  
Host:       IBMac.local
Executable: /Users/parag/Desktop/mpiTest/build/Debug/mpiTest
Cannot continue.**

Comment: First lets make sure your program runs without `mpiexec` in the picture. If you go into `/Users/parag/Desktop/mpiTest/build/Debug` and type `./mpiTest` does your program run?

Comment: mpiTest is working fine from XCode. but its not working from terminal.

Comment: Since this is going to turn into a conversation, I created a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/4144/open-mpi-in-xcode-3-2-6. Please visit that to continue.

Comment: i am in /Users/parag/Desktop/mpiTest/build/Debug/mpiTest.app/Contents/MacOS this directory and now its working fine from terminal.

Comment: That means you created a Cocoa app, not a command-line tool as described in the article you referenced. You probably want to start over and create a command-line tool this time. I don't know for sure, but I expect `mpiexec` will not work with a Cocoa app.

Comment: @SSteave  i am getting same output for command-line app and cocoa app. Process 8566 is 0 of 1 processes
pi is approximately 3.1415926535897309, Error is 0.0000000000000622. my code is running only one process from xcode but when i am running my code from terminal it working fine(creating four processes).